# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, segmentation-fault

At Line 40 my code stops running and outputs signal: segmentation fault(cored dumped), and I am confused to why my code is segmentation faulting since i am not accessing any index out of bounds nor am I modifying a string literal. Baiscally, If the value (k + i) is greater than N, i want to iterate backwards until there is a spot "." in array(patches) to place either a patch "H" or "G".

Here is the the input i am taking in:
1
5 4
GHHGG

Here is the code I wrote:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
int main() {
string cows;
int CONST_N = 100000;
array<string, 100000> patches;
int t, n, k, patchCounter{}; cin >> t;
  while(t--){ 
    patchCounter = 0;
    cin >> n; cin >> k;
    cin >> cows;
  //  cout << n << endl;
    for(int i = 0 ;i < CONST_N;i++){
  patches[i] = "N";
}
    for(int i = 0 ;i < n ;i++){
      patches[i] = ".";
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n ;i++){
      if(cows.substr(i, 1) == "G"){
        if(patches[k + i] == "N"){
          for(int j = n - 1; j >=0;j++){
            if(patches[j] == "."){
              patches[j] = "G";
              break;
            }
        }
          } else {
          patches[k+i] = "G"; i+=(2*k); patchCounter++; 
          }
        }
      }
    for(int i = 0; i < n ;i++){
      if(cows.substr(i,1) == "H"){
         // cout<<(patches[k +i]  == "N") << endl;
        //cout << patches[k +i] << endl;
         if(patches[k + i] == "N"){
           cout << "hello";
          for(int j = n - 1; j >=0;j++){
            if(patches[j] == "."){
              patches[j] = "H";
              break;
            }
        }
          } else {
          patches[k+i] = "H"; i+=(2*k); patchCounter++; 
          }
        }
      }
    cout << patchCounter << endl;
    for(int i = 0 ;i < n ;i++){
      cout << patches[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
 
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I was unsure what to do since array size is 10^5 and i am only accessing index 6 so i am very confused what's happening. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Use your debugger, find out what the values of all the variables are at the time of the  crash, and take it from there.

Comment: `array<string, 100000> patches;` might exceed the default stack limit, which can be as little as 1Mb.

Comment: FWIW you don't need to use `substr` to check a single character in a string. Use the subscript operator (`cows[x]`) to retrieve the character you want to check. You can also get by with an array of characters instead of strings

Comment: `array<string, 100000> patches;` is likely a stack overflow.

Comment: BTW Since it seems that patches is always a single character, you could save a lot of memory with `array<char,100000> patches;`. Maybe save yourself a stack overflow too.

Comment: `array<string, 100000> patches;` -- Just because the constraints say "the input can have up to 100000 items" doesn't mean you should lazily declare an array of 100000 items.  What if the actual input only contains 10 items?  You have 99990 integers that do absolutely nothing except waste stack space.  I see this all the time with a lot code that is produced to answer those "competitive coding" questions, and that is to declare gigantic arrays like this.  Instead, use `std::vector` and *dynamically* add items to it.

Comment: Which debugger are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have a typo, here

```
for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j++) {
    if (patches[j] == ".") {
        patches[j] = "H";
        break;
    }
}
```

should be

```
for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) { // TYPO -- not ++
    if (patches[j] == ".") {
        patches[j] = "H";
        break;
    }
}
```

Honestly this took me 30 seconds to discover with a debugger.